# Finding an element in array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    number: [{
          id : 10,
      },
      {
          id: 20,
      }    
    ]
}
...
render() {
    const { number } = this.state;
    return (
        {number.map(numbers => (
            <div>
               {numbers[1]}
            </div>
        ))}
    )
}
...
```

`{numbers[1]}` is not working.I want to see 20 on the screen. I looked at  https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html but I could not find a solution. How can i fix it. Thank you.

Comment: based on what condition, do you want to filter out only 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbers[1]` not valid since numbers will be an object like `{id: 20}` and what you want is to render the id of the object, you would first filter our the objects that you wish to use and then map and render like

```
render() {
   const { number } = this.state;
   return (
       {number.filter(data => {
          return data.id == 20; // any condition here
       }).map(numbers => (
          <div>
            {numbers.id}
          </div>
       ))}
   )
}
```

If you just want to access a single element, you would simply write

```
render() {
   const { number } = this.state;
   return (
       <div>
          {number[1].id}
       </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Sorry i did not ask the explanatory question, i want just like this. https://jsfiddle.net/0e8egxzk/

Answer (score 0):

You are using map function on the array, so you will get each object in 'numbers' field one by one.

[Map function in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Hope this helps.